# How to create OOP Class in Javascript

Tags: javascript, oop

I'm hesitant to use just any tutorial because I know how those tutorials can end up being, teaching you bad ways to do things.  I want to setup a class in Javascript, so that I can just do

```
var vehicle = new Vehicle(el);
var model = vehicle->getModel();
```

These functions would read the HTML and get and manage the elements on the page.  I'm current doing a setup like...

```
var model = function () {
 return {
  getName: function () {

  },
  getVehicleCount: function () {

  },
  incrementCount: function (id) {
   console.log(x);
  }
 }
}();
```

I'm still learning classes in Javascript... I'd like to be able to pass the class a node for the element all of the methods will use, but I'm not sure I'm doing this right...

Comment: There are classes in js?

Comment: Delnan makes an important point. Javascript is a clasless OO language.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is no such thing as a class in JavaScript, instead everything in JavaScript is an object.

To create a new object you define a function that uses the `this` keyword in it (a “constructor function”), and then call it with the `new` operator:

```
function Foo (id) { // By convention, constructor functions start with a capital letter
    this.id = id;
}

var foo1 = new Foo(1);
var foo2 = new Foo(2);
```

However, these objects have no methods. To add methods, you need to define a prototype object on their constructor function:

```
Foo.prototype = {
    getId: function () {
        return this.id;
    }
}
```

This new `getId` function will be usable by all `Foo` objects. However, as was stated, there are no classes in JavaScript and as such there are other constructs you will use in order to produce different results.

I highly recommend the videos by Douglas Crockford in which he explains much of the javascript OO nature. The talks can be found here:

http://developer.yahoo.com/yui/theater/

Douglas Crockford — The JavaScript Programming Language

Douglas Crockford — Advanced JavaScript

Those will give you a basic understanding of the structure of javascript and should help the transition from classical to functional programming.

Answer (score 1):

Although there are no classes in JavaScript, you can create constructor functions. A constructor function works by binding methods to an objects prototype. There are several ways to do this, each with advantages and disadvantages. I personally prefer the most straigthforward way, which works by appending methods to "this":

```
var Constructor = function() {

  //object properties can be declared directly
  this.property = "value";

  //to add a method simply use dot notation to assign an anonymous function to an object
  //property
  this.method = function () {
    //some code
  }

  //you can even add private functions here. This function will only be visible to this object methods
  function private() {
    //some code
  }
  //use return this at the end to allow chaining like in var object = new Constructor().method();
  return this; 

}
```

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing like classes in JavaScript. JavaScripts inheritance works with prototypes. You can take a look at [base2](http://code.google.com/p/base2/), which mimics class-like behaviour in JavaScript.