# javascript OOP nesting properties

Tags: javascript, oop

What I'm trying to achieve is the following structure for an object. Note that all properties values are constant strings:

```
ObjA
    ObjB
        prop1
        prop2
        prop3
    ObjC
        prop4
        prop5
    .
    .
    .
```

So shoud it be possible to access the properties value using the following sintax:

```
alert(ObjA.ObjC.pro4);
```

So far, I've tried something like the following without success.

```
    var csi = new Object();
    var cao98 = new Object();
    csi.cao98="";
    csi.cao98.rgi = "NRRGILIG";
    alert (csi.cao98.rgi);
```

Is it possible? I do not want to get to far on this issue since there's a lot of discussion on this theme.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3771961/how-to-create-oop-class-in-javascript?rq=1
Please do a search before asking questions.

Comment: Insted of " = new Object();" you should use " = {};"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On your third line you’re assigning an empty string to the `cao98` property of your `csi` object.

I think you mean this instead:

```
var csi = new Object();
var cao98 = new Object();
csi.cao98=cao98;
csi.cao98.rgi = "NRRGILIG";
alert (csi.cao98.rgi);
```

If you’re just literally defining your objects like this, you could use the object literal syntax instead:

```
var csi = {
    cao98: {
        rgi: "NRRGILIG"
    }
};

alert (csi.cao98.rgi);
```

The best approach depends on the context in which you’re using the objects.

Comment: So is it ok to construct this way? I mean, there should be dozens of 'nested' objects.

Comment: Is it ok to construct *which* way? I don’t think there’s much difference between the two, although there is a Stack Overflow question on the subject: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4597926/creating-objects-new-object-or-object-literal-notation

Comment: The object literal syntax is arguably more readable, when indented. (JSON is sort of a subset of JavaScript’s object literal syntax, so it’s got a reasonable chance of looking familiar even to non-JavaScript programmers too.)

Answer (score 2):

If you just want plain objects, you can write that all into one expression using the literal syntax for objects:

```
var ObjA = {
        ObjB: {
            prop1: 'hello',
            prop2: 'howdy'
        },
        ObjC: {
            prop1: 'hi',
            prop2: 'world'
        }
    }
}

console.log(ObjA.ObjB.prop1 + ' ' + ObjA.ObjC.prop2);
```

Answer (score 0):

try

```
    var csi = {
        cao: {
            rgi: 'NRRGILIG'
        }
    };
```